# How can I draw a diagonal line with Console.SetCursorPosition c#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, cursor-position

I need to do a function that received 3 entiers: horizontal and vertical position of the beginning of the line, as well as its length, and draws the diagonal line descending to the left. I don't understand how i can do the diagonal line. I have done a loop for do a horizontal line but I don't know what i need to change for draw a diagonal line.

For the horizontal line, I have done:

```
    static void LigneHorizontale(int posh, int pov, int longueur)
    {

            for (int i = 0; i < longueur; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(posh+i, pov);
                Console.WriteLine("-");
            }
    }
```

Comment: A horizontal line is just a longer string filled with dashes. Like "------------". You can generate strings with a character of your choosing with a length of your choosing.`Console.WriteLine(new string('-', length));`

Comment: _Console.SetCursorPosition(posh+i, pov+i);_ Do add checks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a `CursorPosition` to a given location, then need to draw a horizontal line.

Like,

```
public static void LineHorizontale(int x, int y, int length)
{
    //This will set your cursor position on x and y
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);

    //This will draw '-' n times here n is length
    Console.WriteLine(new String('-', length));
}
```

if you want to print diagonal line then use `\` instead of `-` and increase x and y position.

something like,

```
    public static void LineDiagonal(int x, int y, int length)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            //This will set your cursor position on x and y
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x+i, y+i);

            //This will draw '\' n times here n is length
            Console.Write(@"\");

        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And for draw a diagonal line, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the X:

```
    public static void LineHorizontale(int x, int y, int length)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y);
            Console.Write("-");
        }
    }
```

Diagonal:

```
public static void LineDiaglonal(int x, int y, int length)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x + i, y + i);
        Console.Write('\\');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you any idea for a diagonal line?

Comment: Yes. Just add the '+ i' to y.